# How to select specific properties of object where aren't null in ES6?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I want to select specific object properties where they aren't `null`.

I want to select `id` and `name` of this **object:**

```
{
    "description": "hello",
    "title": "Update",
    "id": "1",
    "name": null
}
```

**expected output:**

```
{
    "id": "1",
    // no name because it's null
}
```

I tried to do that using this **code**:

```
const { title, description, ...newValues } = values;
console.log(newValues);
```

Comment: `const result = {  id: obj.id  };`

Comment: Do you want to select only the `id` property that is not `null`?

Comment: @SAM. I want to select id and name only BUT don't include either of them if they are null.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Grab all keys with [Object.keys](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) and then using [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) to get the selected property only that is not `null`.

You can use condition either `obj[curr]` or `obj[curr] !== null`

```js
const obj = {
  description: "hello",
  title: "Update",
  id: "1",
  name: null,
};

const selected = ["id", "name"];

const result = Object.keys(obj).reduce((acc, curr) => {
  if (selected.includes(curr) && obj[curr]) {
    acc[curr] = obj[curr];
  }
  return acc;
}, {});

console.log(result);
```

Comment: I really appreciate your comment but OP wants to check only for `null` values

Answer (score 2):

You can filter all null elements by converting them to an entries array and then back to an object:

```
const filteredNewValues = Object.fromEntries(Object.entries(newValues).filter(e => e[1]))
```

Browser-Support is limited. So use a polyfill if you need to use it in old browsers. See [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries).

Comment: Note that you should explicitly test against `null` and/or `undefined` (`e[1] == null` or `e[1] === null`) otherwise you will filter out other falsy values (such as `0`).

Answer (score 0):

```
let data = {
    "description": "hello",
    "title": "Update",
    "id": "1",
    "name": null
}

let filteredData = data.name && data.id ? {id: data.id, name: data.name} : undefined
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay, let's assume that you want to make it in a dynamic way.

```
/**
 * Get wanted properties of an object
 * @param object
 * @param {string[]} keys
 */
function cloneObject(obj, keys) {
    return keys
        .filter(key => obj[key] !== null)
        .reduce((newObj, key) => {
            newObj[key] = obj[key];
            return newObj;
        }, {});
}
// here you have your wanted keys
let keys = ['id', 'name'];
let object = {
    "description": "hello",
    "title": "Update",
    "id": "1",
    "name": null
};
let newObject = cloneObject(object, keys);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could create a simple function to extract only non-null passed keys.

```js
var data = {
"description": null,
"title": "Update",
"id": "1",
"name": false
};

function get(data, keys)
{
return keys.reduce((acc, cur) => {
    return  {...acc, ...(data[cur] !== undefined && data[cur] !== null && {[cur]: data[cur]})}
}, {});
}

console.log(get(data, ["description", "title", "id", "name", "fake"]));
```